# Change input type file text

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change my input type="file" css style like in this image:

[image]

This is my actual code:

```
<div class="control">
        <input name="attachment" id="attachment" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Attachment')) ?>" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getPostValue('attachment')) ?>" class="filestyle" type="file"/><i class="fas fa-paperclip"></i>
    </div>
    <label class="control-label" for="attachment"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Attachment (Optional)') ?></span></label>
</div>
```

and like this look now:

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try putting summy ```div``` instead of  ```input``` and then sytle it as you want. then handle onclick of that dummy div and trigger input click

Comment: show the `CSS` that you have given to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code:

```css
label.custom_file {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 8px;
  height: 45px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
 }

 label.custom_file:before {
  content: '\f0c6';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0px;
  padding: 9px 15px;
  height: 45px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
 }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title> Example</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
 href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css"> 
</head>

<body>
 <div class="form-group">
  <input type="file" class="form-control" id="file" style="display: none;">
  <label for="file" class="custom_file"> Attachment(optional)</label>
 </div>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```